# How can I tell, from a script, if "git cherry-pick" fails?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

If the cherry-pick fails due to a merge conflict, it just returns an exit status of 0.

Please don't tell me about `--abort`.  I need to detect, in a script, if the original cherry-pick command fails.

Using git version 1.8.3.1 on CentOS 7.2.

EDIT: my script was doing the cherry-pick in an `if !` and I didn't exit properly in the `then` clause with a non-zero exit.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Is it a bash script or batch?

Comment: I don't know what OS you're on, but on linux with git >=2.0, I find that `cherry-pick` does indeed return a meaningful return code. I have mission-critical code that depends on this fact and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Using git 1.8.  I guess I'll have to look into upgrading.  Which exact git version are you using?

Comment: Frustrating part is I'm on CentOS 7.latest and I really don't want to upgrade git outside of the CentOS repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$?` holds the return code of the last process run in bash.

```
$ ls /dev/null/foo
ls: /dev/null/foo: Not a directory
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: The return value is 0 if there is a merge conflict.

Comment: If you edit your answer, I'll upvote it.  My answer is locked until you do so.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `git status` or equivalent and inspect its output for a normal "1 ahead of tracking" status or a "merge" status.

Comment: That's pretty horrible, especially if a series of cherry-picks are being done.  However, if no other solution shows up, I guess this is it.

Comment: Well, you're using a commandline client to do automated things. Think about using libgit2 instead, I bet it has a better way to do what you want. You can use it from virtually any language.